# Update Contact using Microsoft Graph Client Library

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

How do you update a Contact using the Microsoft Graph Client Library (v1.5)?  I cannot find any documentation on the project page or via Google.

In the sample code below I want to set the SpouseName for all Contacts to "Single".  I have no idea how to commit the change.

```
_graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(_Authenticator);

            var request = _graphClient.Me.Contacts.Request();
            var contacts = await request.GetAsync();

            while (contacts.Count > 0)
            {
                foreach (var ct in contacts)
                {
                    ct.SpouseName = "Single"; 
                    //
                    // how do you commit this change?
                    //
                }
                if (contacts.NextPageRequest != null)
                {
                    contacts = await contacts.NextPageRequest.GetAsync();
                }
                else
                {
                    break;
                }

            }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use the `UpdateAsync()` method:

```cs
await graphClient.Me.Contacts["id"].Request().UpdateAsync(new Contact()
{
    SpouseName = "Single"
});
```

Note that you only pass in the property you want to change. Do not pass the entire `Contact` object you previously retrieved.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be a Request method on the Microsoft.Graph.Contact object.  Could I be missing a reference that would extend this method?

Comment: I've updated my answer to clarify the code. Also, make sure you're using the latest version of the [SDK](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet).